# Inserting values of a column from one dataframe to another while respecting a given condition

Tags: sql, r, sqldf

I have two data frames `d1` and `d2`. `d2` has a column which contains data that I would prefer to be added to `d1`.

Each of the data frames have equal number of rows and columns.

```
> d1
     t1  t2 numVehicles avgByRunRep
1   0.2 0.3          10    225.5000
2   0.2 0.4          10    219.6667
3   0.2 0.5          10    205.1667
4   0.2 0.6          10    220.6667
5   0.2 0.7          10    205.1667

> d2
     t1  t2 numVehicles avgLostPerRep
1   0.2 0.3          10     14.333333
2   0.2 0.4          10      9.000000
3   0.2 0.5          10      8.000000
4   0.2 0.6          10      8.000000
5   0.2 0.7          10      6.833333
```

So I would like the values in `d2`'s `avgLostPerRep` column to be "transferred" to `d1` by matching `t1`, `t2`, `numVehicles`.

So in the end `d1` would look something like:

```
> d1
     t1  t2 numVehicles avgByRunRep  avgLostPerRep
1   0.2 0.3          10    225.5000  14.333333
2   0.2 0.4          10    219.6667  9.000000
3   0.2 0.5          10    205.1667  8.000000
4   0.2 0.6          10    220.6667  8.000000
5   0.2 0.7          10    205.1667  6.833333
```

It is also possible to save the final resulting data frame in another variable `d3`, if that makes any difference at all.

I would like to know how this can be solved with `sqldf` but pure `R` is OK as well.

I tried `merge` from R, but got a big data-frame with a lot of `NA`. I also tried `UPDATE` and `INSERT INTO` for `sqldf` to no avail.

Comment: `merge(d1, d2, by=c('t1', 't2', 'numVehicles'))` gives the expected output though, or using `data.table` `library(data.table);setkey(setDT(d1), t1, t2, numVehicles)[d2]`

Comment: I just tried this one as well: `temp <- merge(d1, d2, all.x=T, sort=F)` and I got the expected output. Would you mind explaining the difference between the two commands, and how they work?

Comment: simply `merge(d1, d2)` also works in the example data as the common columns in both datasets are used in the `by=`.  Could you show the code that didn't work?

Comment: `query = "SELECT a.t1, a.t2, a.numVehicles, a.avgByRunRep, b.avgLostPerRep FROM d1 a INNER JOIN d2 b WHERE a.t2=b.t2"`

`sqldf(query)`

That's some sqldf for you. Quite the long line of code there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** This performs a left join along the indicated columns:

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("select * from d1 left join d2 using(t1, t2, numVehicles)")
```

We could alternately use a left natural join which causes the join to occur along commonly named columns:

```
sqldf("select * from d1 left natural join d2")
```

For the data shown in the question we could alternately use an inner join by simply omitting the word `left` in either of the above; however, if the actual data does not have a value in `d2` for every row of `d1` then the inner join would omit those rows of `d1` whereas the left join would include them and add `NA` for the joined `d2` column.

**2)** The corresponding native R code would be this for the first sqldf statement

```
merge(d1, d2, all.x = TRUE, by = 1:3)
```

and this for the second:

```
merge(d1, d2, all.x = TRUE)
```

Inner joins are obtained by omitting the `all.x = TRUE` in either case.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try data.table package as long as your question is pretty straightforward with it's syntax and keys and merge will be much faster than base R

Recreating initial data sets:

```
library(data.table)

d1<- fread("t1,t2,numVehicles,avgByRunRep
0.2,0.3,10,225.5000
0.2,0.4,10,219.6667
0.2,0.5,10,205.1667
0.2,0.6,10,220.6667
0.2,0.7,10,205.1667")

# setting desired columns as keys is important in your case
# and setkey(d1) would be enough to use all columns in d1
setkey(d1, t1, t2, numVehicles) 

d2<- fread("t1,t2,numVehicles,avgLostPerRep
0.2,0.3,10,14.333333
0.2,0.4,10,9.000000
0.2,0.5,10,8.000000
0.2,0.6,10,8.000000
0.2,0.7,10,6.833333")
```

Solution:

```
merge(d1, d2)
# t1  t2 numVehicles avgByRunRep avgLostPerRep
#1: 0.2 0.3          10    225.5000     14.333333
#2: 0.2 0.4          10    219.6667      9.000000
#3: 0.2 0.5          10    205.1667      8.000000
#4: 0.2 0.6          10    220.6667      8.000000
#5: 0.2 0.7          10    205.1667      6.833333
```

Answer (score 0):

Base R:

`merge(d1, d2)`

sqldf:

```
library(sqldf)
query = "SELECT a.t1, a.t2, a.numVehicles, a.avgByRunRep, b.avgLostPerRep FROM d1 a INNER JOIN d2 b WHERE a.t2=b.t2"
sqldf(query)
```